# is there a way to substring an array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, substr

i want to substring an array given by the query

***CONTROLLER*** (EX. value (Year_Report_2019, Year_Report_2020)

```
 $store=array();

 $tables = \DB::select("SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_database LIKE '%Year_Report_%'");

    foreach($tables as $this){

     $get= substr($this,-4);

     $store[] = $get;
   }
```

***BLADE***  want show result of (2019,2020)

```
{{implode(",", $store)}}
```

***ERROR***

```
substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Comment: solved my problem ty guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You parsed your result wrong. (avoid using variable name `$this`)

```php
$store=array();

$tables = \DB::select("SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_database LIKE '%Year_Report_%'");

foreach($tables as $table){
    $store[] = substr($table->Tables_in_database,-4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `implode` function will do it for you:

```
{{implode(",", $store)}}
```

PHP docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: Your error is not related to concatenating the array. Check out this doc on how database queries work in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database . Basically you get an array of objects when you do `DB::select(...)`, not array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = ['Year_Report_2019','Year_Report_2020'];


array_walk($array, function(&$item) { 
    return $item = preg_replace("/\D/", '', $item);
});
```

First you can form your array the way you want, keeping only the integer values. This action can happen in your controller so you don't have array handling in your view.

Then in your view you can return and display your new array as comma separated string using:

```
  {{ implode(",",$array) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use foreach here Just implode this array with your desire expression

```
{{implode(",", $store)}}
```